# How can I pass Path parameters to lua code by nginx?

Tags: nginx, lua

I want to create a Location in my Nginx with such route **/resource/{{state}}** though the {{state}} is a place holder for a variable that must pass to my Lua script and according to this variable I want to process some resources.

I cannot find any documentation or guideline for creating such a route in Nginx and passing path parameters to Lua. Are path parameters available in nginx and if the answer is yes how can I access them in mylua code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex [location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) syntax with the [ngx.var.VARIABLE](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxvarvariable) API:

```
location ~ ^/resource/(?<state>[^/]+)/?$ {
    content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.say(ngx.var.state)
    }
}
```

Note: nginx uses the [PCRE2](https://www.pcre.org/) library for regex support. Check the [documentation](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html) for the syntax.